# Is is possible to get multiple pojo class with different fields using one @postmapping in one controller class

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have 3 POJO classes with different fields and three repositories related to that POJO classes and I have one controller class that has one @postmapping. so can I get those three pooja classes field by using one postmapping. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a map of string and Object. String will be 
`simpleClassName` and value will be your pojos. Think that is the simplest solution.